# Bootstrap modify breadcrumb with fontawesome icon separator with SASS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

So I'm trying to change the default `breadcrumb` style with SASS. I've setup everything as mentioned in the official Bootstrap 4 beta 3 docs. I've changed the following in the `custom.scss`

```
$breadcrumb-divider: "\f105"; //fontawesome icon for fa-angle-right
```

Now this also needs font family to set to

```
font-family: 'fontAwesome'; //How do I plug this in
```

How do you setup the font for the `.breadcrumb-item::before` class in the right way?

Comment: You tried just targeting it like normal? `.breadcrumb-item {font-family: 'fontAwesome';}`

Comment: I tried the above it works, but if I inspect the element style it has two different blocks of style getting added using the same selector. So it has one block with the styles that are coming from bootstrap and a second block for the style above. Is that the right way?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
.breadcrumb-item::before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f105";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The actual tag as listed in breadcrumb.scss is:

```
    .breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item::before {
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
      content: "\f101" !important; 
    }
```

The `!important` should overwrite the standard styling set.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Bootstrap 4 and Font Awesome 5,

```
.breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f105";
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are defining a variable for the scss like:

```
$breadcrumb-divider: "\f105";
```

now you have to set this variable in the pseudo-element `::before` `content` property. and also apply the font shorthand property to it.

```
.breadcrumb-item+.breadcrumb-item::before{
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  content: $breadcrumb-divider;
}
```

I think it should be work please try it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To change the separator from the standard "/" to ">>" without using an icon library or messing with a svg, here is the css snippet which can be applied via a custom class 'breadcrumb-custom' on
the 'ol' tag.

```
.breadcrumb-custom  .breadcrumb-item +  .breadcrumb-item::before { 
  content: ">>"; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  color: #000000; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit late to the party, but I wanted to give an updated answer for current library versions.

If you are using Bootstrap 5 and FontAwesome 5, this SCSS will work.

```
.breadcrumb-item {
    + .breadcrumb-item {
        &::before {
            font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
            font-weight: 700;
            content: "\f054" !important;
        }
    }
}
```