# FontAwesome Pro icons and Bootstrap 4 breadcrumbs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, font-awesome-5

This has been asked many times before, but nothing I'm seeing as an answer is working, e.g. [Bootstrap modify breadcrumb with fontawesome icon separator with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152733/bootstrap-modify-breadcrumb-with-fontawesome-icon-separator-with-sass)

I'm using Font Awesome 5 Pro (from their own CDN, `kit.fontawesome.com`) and Bootstrap 4.0.0

I want to change the default Bootstrap 4 breadcrumb separator to a FontAwesome icon.

I have the following markup:

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Library</li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

If I apply any of the answers given, it doesn't render correctly. I get a "square".

I'm using the unicode `f061` which should be the "right arrow" shown here: https://fontawesome.com/icons/arrow-right

Examples -

```
.breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item::before {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
    content: "\f061";
}
```

[image]

```
.breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
    content: "\f061";
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

[image]

Edit - it's working fine for rendering icons inside the document, e.g. `<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>` will work. It's only when I'm trying to reference it in the CSS it's not showing the icon. There are no 404 errors or issues loading resources.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Have you defined the font-family `Font Awesome 5 Pro` in your CSS file, and are the src valid?

Comment: What do you mean by "defined"? Have a look at some of the other things posted here.. It's working for rendering icons inside the document. But when I'm trying to reference it in the CSS it's not. All of the answers I've seen say the `font-family` name is "Font Awesome 5 Pro" which makes sense since that's the version we're using (as opposed to the Free one, etc).

Comment: Actually, it would be defined in the FA CSS file, that you linking to actually, so ignore that comment. If you inspect it, is everything look valid there?

Comment: The file we're linking to is a `.js` file. It's provided through FontAwesome's control panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have use bolder right arrow so you have to add `font-weight:900`.

follow the snippet code of my answer it works perfectly.

```css
.breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f061";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <title>Teste</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a35ed2bddb.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Library</li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How many people are not reading the bounty description? It says we are NOT using the .css version (but the .js version) and we are using the Pro version, not the Free version. I'm sure it does work if you use a completely different thing to what the question is asking about...

Comment: as per your comment i have make changes in my answer you have to add font-weight to your icon css. please review my upgraded answer. Thank You...

Comment: This didn't actually work for me. But it helped me narrow down the issue. If I replace the .js file with the one you've linked to it works. However, when I'm linking to the one I had, it doesn't. This is very annoying because it's a URL that FontAwesome have provided within their control panel to a file on their own CDN! I've awarded the bounty to you but other than contacting FA to ask I'm still unsure why the file they've provided doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing the css file for solid type. Here is the definition in my project.

```
@import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/solid.scss';
@import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/light.scss';
@import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/regular.scss';
```

Comment: It's the version that's hosted on their CDN. They only provide a link to a `.js` file which is included inside `<head>`. There's no other files to import/include. This is as described on their own website so surely it must work?

Comment: Does the normal implement work?

```
<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
```

Comment: Yes it's working fine for rendering icons inside the document. It's just when I'm trying to reference it in the CSS it's not showing the correct icon. There are no 404 errors or issues loading resources

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the `Rendered Font` in computed to make sure your css not override by others

[image]

Comment: It isn't showing FontAwesome. And strangely if I use an actual class such as `<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>` in the HTML, in renders the icon correctly...but doesn't show that font under Rendered Fonts. I can't understand that at all!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use !important?

```
.breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro" !important;
    content: "\f061" !important;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to your project so we could look directly on the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's on a private domain and I can't make a fiddle because the .js we're linking to from FontAwesome's CDN has to be tied to the domain where the site is running from.

Comment: Hah that could be actually the problem... that its a private domain... remove that CDN and download fontawesome pro bundle and use it on locally on your server... its muchbetter for performance anyway and the problem should dissapear..

Comment: Please read the notes on the bounty and you'll see why that's not the answer we're looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

For this icon you should be able to use the "Font Awesome\ 5 Free" family. Notice that the `\` and font-weight are also needed...

```
.breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item:before {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
    content: "\f061";
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/aIGotMzZt4

Comment: We're using Font Awesome 5 *Pro*. The "Free" font family doesn't work in this situation as far as I can tell. I tried updating the `font-family` as per my question but it still renders a square. The `\` is interesting as I didn't know that was required. This might be along the right lines but hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Did you try:`font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Pro';` ?

Comment: Yeah. It still renders the squares.

Comment: Have you tried their support? https://fontawesome.com/support Hard to say w/o being able to reproduce and most likely something with referencing the Pro fonts and WOFF fles. Also referencing the "Free" set on CDN (which seems to work fine) would be another good way to troubleshoot if it's the Pro set or something else.